# Gesture to hide rising notification in MacBook?

Tags: keyboard, notifications, trackpad

Is there a keyboard shortcut or hand gesture to quickly hide notification popups from the notification center when they're arriving? (the whole notifications bar is of course closed, and only the new arriving notification is shown)

This is instead of clicking the very little "X" on the small window

Comment: Instead of Alert one can set notification to Banner. Difference being: 'Banners appear in the upper-right corner and go away automatically. Alerts stay on screen until dismissed'.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Thanks. Is it possible to decrease the waiting time (in seconds) of the Alert's automatic dismissing?

Answer (score 1):

These steps were tested using macOS Big Sur 11.2.1.

To dismiss an alert-style notification without clicking the little "x", you can utilize the following options:

1. If you're using a trackpad, hover your cursor over the alert-style notification then swipe right using two fingers.
2. If you're using a mouse, hover your cursor over the alert-style notification then click and drag the notification to the right.

Comment: +1, these actions have worked since notifications were introduced to macOS.

Comment: I will check that in my next notification. By the way, is it possible to decrease the waiting time (in seconds) of the Alert's automatic dismissing?

Comment: There are two types of visual notifications: Banners and Alerts. Alerts will persist until they are acknowledged or dismissed. Banners will automatically dismiss themselves after a set time. There isn't a method of adjusting the Banner duration in System Preferences, but you may be able to adjust it by running the following command in Terminal: `defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime -int 10`. Please note the "10" represents the number of seconds that the Banner will persist. You can change this number to your preference.